# JavaScript value not being received by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having trouble with a program that I have written. The idea is that I click a link and the value of the link is picked up in a JavaScript variable. I then do a GET request to send the value to a PHP variable and print it out.

Here is the code:

**The HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='mydiv'>
            <a href='/codeigniter/index.php/hashtest/hi'>Link 1</a>
            <a href='/codeigniter/index.php/hashtest/hi'>Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The jQuery** (in a `<script>` tag within the above body)

```
$(function()
{
    var mydiv = $('#mydiv');
    mydiv.on('click', 'a', function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log(text);
        //$.get("hashtest.php", {qwerty: text});
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "/codeigniter/index.php/hashtest/hi",
            data: {
                qwerty : text
            },
            async: "false",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("success!");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error)
            {

                alert("Status : " + status + " error: " + error); 
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

**The PHP**

```
class Hashtest extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function hi() {
        $x = $this->input->get('qwerty');
        print $x;
        print "";
    }

}
```

The error:

```
NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user
```

At the moment, the JavaScript correctly gets the right link value as the console.log() line outputs the right thing for both links. But it seems the PHP is not receiving this value because nothing is being printed out. I've tried replacing the variable with a hard-coded string but it makes no difference. I can print static PHP from within the method above so I don't think it's an issue where I can't print any PHP at all.

A few points:

- I used $.ajax instead of $.get just to see what error message would
  appear (ideally I'd want to use $.get though). It seems it's some
  sort of uncaught exception based on what I've read about the above
  error message and the fact that the alert box that appears doesn't
  show an error message, just a status of "error".
- I don't expect any value back, the success method is just there to
  see if the request is wokring or not (which it currently isn't)
- I am assuming that the id of the link is unknown.
- The code is all within the same class and the URL that I'm pointing
  to in the AJAX request is correct (I got a HTTP 200 code back in my
  browser console).
- The PHP was written using the CodeIgniter framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of following the link:

```
$(function()
  {
      var mydiv = $('#mydiv');
      mydiv.on('click', 'a', function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); // <-- THIS IS NEEDED
          var text = $(this).text();
          console.log(text);
          //$.get("hashtest.php", {qwerty: text});
          $.ajax
          ({
              url: "/codeigniter/index.php/hashtest/hi",
              data: {qwerty : text},
              async: "false",
              success: function(data){
                  console.log("success!");
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, status, error)
              {

                  alert("Status : " + status + " error: " + error); 
              } 
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Adding that in removes the error and the code passes through the "success" method rather than the "error" method but the PHP still won't print.

Comment: Where do you expect it to print? The output of the PHP is in `data`, and you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: OK for some odd reason `data` contains all the HTML, jQuery and PHP. The $x variable does now contain the right value but it still isn't displaying on the browser when I try to print it out.

Comment: It won't display in the browser unless you put it there, e.g. `$("#somediv").text(data)`.

Comment: Drat! You're right. Forgot that the print statement is just there to return something to the JavaScript. Still doesn't explain why data contains all the HTML, jQuery and PHP though. That natually gets outputted to the browser when I use the `text()` method.

Comment: Did you put `<?php` at the beginning of the script? Or try renaming the script to `hi.php`.

Comment: I've used `<?php` at the top and changing the file name to `hi.php` causes this error: `Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\hi.php:308)`

Comment: If you call `header()`, `setcookie()`, or `session_start()`, make sure you do it before you output anything.

Comment: I'm not doing any of that though - no cookies or sessions at all.

Comment: Nothing, not even a comment.

Comment: Make sure you're reading the error correctly. I'm not talking about line 308. The rest of the message should say "in /path/to/file.php on line XXX", XXX is the relevant line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php/8028987#8028987

Comment: That's the line I mentioned - the last line of the script which just has a HTML comment `</html> -->` (there was whitespace below initially (which is why I said there was nothing at all first) but I removed it)

Comment: Maybe you're using a library that sends headers, you need to initialize the library before you get to line 308 of the script.

Comment: I'm not using any libraries except for calling the jQuery CDN. In the PHP I use $this->input->get() but that doesn't need the initialisation of a library, just to call the constructor of the parent controller class (which I have done)

Comment: PHP doesn't just make up things like this. If you want help with that error, post a new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but your not stopping the event when you click on the link.

Add e.preventDefault();

`var mydiv = $('#mydiv');`

```
            mydiv.on('click', 'a', function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var text = $(this).text();

      </code>
```